# How to conduct my first data-analysis study?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, observational-study

I'm trying to improve my understanding of a few basic concepts in statistics (like statistical significance, the p-value, etc.) and to achieve that I decided to do a study myself (trying to learn through doing).

I collected a data set about my chess games that includes my level of alertness, the number of blunders I made in each, the result, etc. My hypothesis is that the more tired I am, the more blunders I make.

I'm kind of clueless of where I start and that's why I'm asking for your help. Is there a good primer book (or a series of articles) that helps me devise the study? Is there a platform where I can plug in my numbers that helps me arrive at the relevant values?

Thank you very much in advance,

Balint

Comment: The design worries me. You are the person who determines whether you are Alert or Sleepy. You are also the person who determines how many blunders were made. If you're not careful, you will blame blunders on lack of sleep and the data might inevitably "demonstrate" that sleepiness causes blunders. // Honestly, my own chess games all seem to be full of blunders regardless how much sleep I've had. One idea to promote objectivity would be to declare your state as Alert or Sleepy at the start of each game depending on hours of sleep the night before and then use wins and losses for data

Comment: The strength of the opponent seems relevant as well, unless you always play against the same opponent and even then (if the opponent is another person), their performance might depend on their lack of sleep, etc.

Comment: Can you post a little sample of your data so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: @BruceET You make a good point about the alertness measure, but many chess engines are capable of telling you when you make a blunder, and so this is less subjective than one might believe.  Additionally, I think your posted answer fails to account for one important detail; blunders are a function of the length of the game.  Short games are likely to have fewer blunders, while lengthy games see more because there are more opportunities for a blunder to happen!

Comment: Trying to envision this as a feasible study for 'first data analysis'.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Sure, here is the full data set: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18HyfdYWG7anCc3YBOkFRet7sdd43cGw-Wd-x_QF00oE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @dipetkov Sorry, I should have explained: the games were played on chess.com. They match you against opponents of roughly the same strength so there's very little variance in this variable (which I thus didn't consider important to track).

Comment: @BruceET I should have specified that it's chess.com (the platform where I played the games) that I used to analyze the games and I simply copied the number of blunders and the accuracy % that they gave me. The only self-assessed variable is the "alertness" score. Your suggestion to instead base it on the number of hours of sleep the previous night makes sense. However, I can be more alert after my afternoon coffee if I'd slept 6 hours than I am at 11pm even though I'd slept 8 hours the night before. At any rate, I can now do better since I have a wearable that gives me a Readiness score :)

Comment: Always best to disclose such info in the Question from the start. Using chess.com makes your project seem much better suited for a 'first data analysis study'.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have 10 games played while Alert with 8 wins,
and 12 games played while Sleepy with 3 wins.

**Test of two binomial proportions.** Then
a `prop.test` in R is as shown below, rejects the null
hypothesis that you do as well whether alert or sleepy, in favor of
the alternative of more blunders when sleepy. The P-value $0.016 < 0.02 = 2\%,$ indicates significance at the 2% level.

```
prop.test(c(8,3), c(10,12), alt="greater")

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(8, 3) out of c(10, 12)
X-squared = 4.5833, df = 1, p-value = 0.01614
alternative hypothesis: greater
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.1658221 1.0000000
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.80   0.25
```

Roughly speaking the test above is based on a normal approximation.
However, this particular test for comparing two binomial proportions
is essentially equivalent to a chi-squared test of independence
(between alertness and wins).

There are several versions of the test to compare two binomial proportions. Some use a continuity correction and some do not.
Some use the null hypothesis to get a pooled estimated standard
error for the estimated difference in the two proportions. Others
find estimated standard errors for the two proportions separately.

You can read more about various versions of tests for
comparing two binomial proportions in intermediate level statistics texts, browsing this site, and googling online.
This [page from NIST](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm) shows the pooled method for estimating
the standard error.

**Chi-squared test for independence.** In R the syntax of `chisq.test` requires data in the form of a $2\times 2$ table as shown below. The rows are for Alert/Sleepy and the columns are for Win/Lose.

```
TAB = rbind(c(8,2), c(3,9));  TAB
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8    2
[2,]    3    9

chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TAB
X-squared = 4.5833, df = 1, p-value = 0.03228
```

This test is inherently a two-sided test, so the P-value is twice
as big as for the one-sided `prop.test` shown previously.

The chi-squared statistic uses the observed counts in `TAB` and
expected counts computed from the row, column, and grand totals
of the table. Expected counts for the data above can be displayed using `$`-notation, as below.

```
chisq.test(TAB)$exp
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]    6    6
```

The expected value at upper left is found as $(10)(11)/22 = 5.$
For the particular data used here, it turns out that all four
expected counts are integers. However, if they are not integers
for your real data, you should not round them when computing the chi-squared statistic.

In this case, all expected counts are $\ge 5,$ which is generally
taken as a requirement for the chi-squared statistic to have
approximately a chi-squared distribution. You might be able to meet this requirement if you use a dozen or more games each for Alert and Sleepy for your real project--and you are about equally matched with your opponents. [If you get warning messages triggered by expected counts that are too small, in R you may be able to simulate a useful P-value, or you could
use Fisher's Exact Test.]

The P-value is found as the probability that the distribution
$\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 1)$ exceeds the chi-squared statistic $4.5833.$
The P-value can be found using R as follows, where `pchis` is a
CDF of a chi-squared distribution. It agrees with the output shown above, except for rounding in the output.

```
1 - pchisq(4.5833, 1)
[1] 0.03228498
```

The critical value of a test at the 5% level is $c =3.8415.$
We would reject the null hypothesis of independence at the 5% level, if the
chi-squared statistic exceeds $c.$

```
qchisq(.95, 1)
[1] 3.841459
```

In the figure below, the P-value of the chi-squared test is the
area under the density curve to the right of the vertical broken line.

```
curve(dchisq(x,1), 0, 8, col="blue", lwd=2, 
      ylab="PDF", main="Density of CHISQ(1)")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=4.5833, col="orange", lwd=2, lty="dashed")
```

[image]

You can find more details about chi-squared tests of independence
(including the Yates continuity correction for small counts) in most elementary statistics texts, by browsing this site, and by googling online.

---

*Speculative Addendum on blunder counts:* If you feel you have an objective definition of 'blunder', then you might compare counts of blunders `b.a` in ten games played while Alert with counts of blunders `b.s`
in a dozen games played while Sleepy. Fictitious data below.

```
b.a
 [1] 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
b.s
 [1] 0 2 2 1 0 1 1 2 1 2 1 1
```

Even if your definition of *blunder* is objective and useful,
there may be difficulties comparing the results, at a beginner's level.
You might do a chi-squared test, treating 0, 1, and 2 as
nominal categories:

```
TBL = rbind(c(6, 4, 0), c(2, 6, 4)); TBL
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    4    0
[2,]    2    6    4

chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 6.27, df = 2, p-value = 0.0435

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Simulating to make up for sparse data, we have significance
at the 4% level.

```
chisq.test(TBL, sim=T)$p.val
[1] 0.03598201
```

Using a 2-sample nonparametric Wilcoxon rank sum test, to treat 0, 1, and 2 as ordinal categories, we get an unreliable P-value
(on account of the many tied values) that hints of significance.

```
wilcox.test(b.a, b.s)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  b.a and b.s
W = 26, p-value = 0.01682
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(b.a, b.s) : 
 cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

*Pretending,* contrary to fact, that the counts are normally distributed, we could
do a 2-sample Welch t test. We get a highly significant P-value but have to wonder if it is realistic.

```
t.test(b.a, b.s)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  b.a and b.s
t = -2.9061, df = 19.645, p-value = 0.008844
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.3176031 -0.2157303
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 0.400000  1.166667
```

If we were to model potential blunders at 10 independent Bernoulli
random events per game, but with different rates for an Alert or Sleepy player, then we might use `prop.test`, which would give
a significant result at the 7% level

```
prop.test(c(4,14), c(100, 120))

        2-sample test for 
        equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(4, 14) out of c(100, 120)
X-squared = 3.3082, df = 1, p-value = 0.06894
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.15492856  0.00159523
sample estimates:
    prop 1    prop 2 
 0.0400000 0.1166667
```

Trying different models and various tests until one of them
happens to turns out to give a significant result, is blatant P-hacking. So you'd
need to settle on a reasonable model and test at the start.

*One last thing:* So far, neither of us has said anything
about your opponent(s) in these chess games. Is it always
the same person who is always alert, a panel of possible
opponents of about the same level as yourself, one of whom is randomly chosen for each of your games, a 'pretty good' computer program that points out your blunders?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question in such great length. I have to admit I felt lost starting from the "Chi-squared test" section but that's because I lack the necessary knowledge. I can now go ahead and read up on those, just as you suggested. Do you know any good books or online courses? (I prefer to go through a book/course instead of scouring for information online.) Thank you!

Comment: About the opponents' strength: they were always different people but always with the same chess level as I was. I drew all data from the chess engine (chess.com) analysis except for the Alertness score.

Answer (score 2):

BruceET gives a lengthy answer, but I believe a better model can developed than a simple test of proportions.

Let $b_i$ be the number of blunders in game $i$.  Let $n_i$ be the number of moves you make in game $i$.  As an avid chess player, I know that blunders are just a fact of life, and when games are lengthy you are more likely to make more simply because *you have lots of opportunities to blunder*.  Hence, we need to account for how many moves you make in each game.

This can be done with simple Poisson regression.  Our model will be

$$ \log(\lambda_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \log(n_i)$$

$$ b_i \sim \mbox{Poisson}(\lambda_i) $$

Here, $\exp(\beta_0)$ is going to be the expected number of blunders you make in a game where you make $n_i$ moves. The term $\log(n_i)$ is known as an offset term and does not have an associated coefficient. As you make more moves, the expected number of blunders will naturally increase.  The variable $x$ is for your measure of alertness, and so $\exp(\beta_1)$ will be the factor by which the number of blunders changes per one unit change in alertness.